# Jenkins not finding GDIplus dependency

Tags: c#, jenkins

I am using a single branch pipeline for a project, currently I am getting this error.

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.0095238]       System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'System.DrawingCore.GDIPlus' threw an exception.
[xUnit.net 00:00:03.0097048]       ---- System.DllNotFoundException : Unable to load DLL 'gdiplus.dll': The specified module could not be found.
```

Whenever I run the same unit tests locally they all pass, however when going through jenkins it is unable to load the gdiplus.dll I am at a loss because I have no idea why this is behaving this way. Has anyone encountered something similar? How can I add the DLL manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has this issue, the best way to solve this is to install the gdiplus in your docker container. However even after you have installed the docker container you will still have this error because Linus in its infinite wisdom is looking for gdiplus.dll not libgdiplus.so so there is a need to link it.........

Here is a link to where I found the solution after hours of searching

https://en.code-bude.net/2017/05/08/net-core-gdiplus-dll-not-found-in-linux/

This is the code I used and it is working

apt-get install -y libgdiplus \
&& cd /usr/lib ln -s libgdiplus.so gdiplus.dll